# Playframework file upload error

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework-2.0

I'm using the [Handling file upload](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaFileUpload) example. When uploading a file, the server shows an error: `Missing boundary header`

Here is what i'm doing:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) {implicit request =>
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
      import java.io.File
      val filename = picture.filename
      val contentType = picture.contentType
      picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/users/pictures"))
      Ok("File uploaded")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file"
      )
    }
  }
```

and in my form I have done this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

<input type="file" name="picture">

<p>
    <input type="submit">
</p>

}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Play! project and used your code, and it seemed to work fine (used latest Chrome on OSX). If you didn't have the `'enctype` parameter, I would understand that error.

[Here's the entire project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58279793/my_app.zip). See if that works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your project worked fine. I really don't know what's wrong with mine. I will try to fix it and comment here if its something usefull.

Comment: The error is fixed when I used the `POST` method in my `routes` file.